# Alert after using sharedmanager

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

This is my code

```
audioViewController *voiceRecorder = [audioViewController sharedManager];
[voiceRecorder stopRecording];
NSString *msg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Want to logout?"];
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Info" 
                                                message:msg 
                                               delegate:self 
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"No" 
                                      otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil];
alert.tag = 100;
[alert show];
```

I am calling sharedManager in one of my view controller. The problem is, my alertview runs before sharedManager method executes, if you check my code, i have called "StopReording" method, but when i run the code, it works after showing alert. Anyone has idea, how do I show alert only after the method returns something.?

Comment: What happens in `sharedManager`?

Comment: like if you see my above code, i am called [voiceRecorder stopRecording]; after initializing sharedmanager. The problem is this method is called after showing alert

Comment: It is impossible in any way. When you say "the method is called", you mean you put a breakpoint at the method's body?

Comment: yes i've alert msg inside stoprecording method as well but when this script is run, the alert msg after stoprecording is called first and then only show alert msg inside the stoprecording method. So in other way i ca say, the stoprecording method is called only after executing all the script. There is something to do with sharedInstance.

Comment: Can you please place your stopRecording code snippet here, just want to check whether there is another thread which runs that or not

Comment: ok i have a viewcontroller named "audioviewcontroller.m"

this is how created sharedinstance
`

- (IBAction) stopRecording {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Info" message:"Sure to stop?" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Yes" otherButtonTitles:@"No", nil];
        [alert show];
 
}
`

Comment: Not this, I asked about stopRecording method. What I am trying to say is - if that method is executing over separate thread then it will allow main thread to execute that alert. So place your stopRecording method in question it self.

Comment: this is my stop code
- (IBAction) stopRecording {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Info" message:@"stop audio?" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Yes" otherButtonTitles:@"No", nil];
    [alert show];
    }
    }

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confusing yourself about method run order and alert presentation order. The methods run in the order specified by your code, they must. What you see on screen is 2 alerts, one (stop) presented first, the the other (logout) presented immediately after.

Generally, you shouldn't show 2 alerts at the same time. Certainly not if they relate to different things.

Present your first alert, then wait for the answer to be received (using the delegate methods). Once you have the users answer, then decide what to do next and present the second alert or continue with some other operation.